# Using my netbook/laptop on bed. No cooling pads or special contraptions

Tags: laptop, netbook, cooling

Do you think that I can improvise a "cooling pad" with my old comp cabinets? I have a bunch of old cabinets that I will never use again. Might as well remove one of the cover plates and use it as a cooling pad. What do you think? I put the plate on my legs and on top of it my netbook while in bed, that way it has a flat aluminum surface with little holes. Should I do it?

Comment: I just use a wooden place-mat so that the blankets/sheets don't block the vents on the top/side of my laptop/netbook... hasn't overheated yet.

Comment: Im trying my comp cabinet shaft as I write, there seems to be no more heat than in my wooden desk. I might keep it like this.

Comment: Do you want a cooling pad (actively or passively draws heat from the laptop and stores or displaces it) or an insulator pad (stops heat transferring to the surface that the laptop is on)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be fine.  Unless you're overclocking the CPU or using it in extremely hot environments, the internal fans should be able to keep the machine cool enough to avoid problems, as long as the vents are clear.  A hard surface like the side of an old computer case will prevent the blankets from blocking the vent holes.  Having holes in whatever hard surface you use isn't really necessary for cooling.  Any hard surface that's a little bigger than the laptop's footprint should do.

Comment: Thank you, I hope this answer can save people some money.